# forEach function much faster than equivalent for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, for-loop, foreach

In an Angular app I am building, I have two pieces of code which fire on every refresh. They both do the same thing, but the faster one is the array forEach function, which I thought was supposed to be slightly *slower*.

If you spot an error, great! But why would the foreach loop be so much faster. They come right after each other, and if I switch the order around, it doesn't make a difference.

First the faster one. This averages about 5 ms using `performance.now()`.

```
var start = performance.now();
start = performance.now();
$scope.config.formTables.forEach(function (e, i, a) {
    ['tbody', 'thead', 'tfoot'].forEach(function (f, j) {
        if (!$scope.config[e][f]) return;
        $scope.config[e][f].forEach(function (g, k) {
            if(isFunction(g.calculated || {})) g.calculated.apply(g);
        })
    })
});
console.log(performance.now() - start);
```

And now the slower one, which I thought should have been faster. This one takes 100-200 ms.

```
start = performance.now();
var i,j,k,e,f,g;
for(i = 0; i < $scope.config.formTables.length; i++){
    e = $scope.config[$scope.config.formTables[i]];
    if(e.thead)
    for(j = 0; j < e.thead.length; j++){
        f = e.thead;
        for(k = 0; k < f.length; k++){
            //g = f[j];
            if(isFunction(f[j].calculated || {})) f[j].calculated.apply(f[j]);
        }
    }
    if(e.tfoot)
    for(j = 0; j < e.tfoot.length; j++){
        f = e.tfoot;
        for(k = 0; k < f.length; k++){
            //g = f[j];
            if(isFunction(f[j].calculated || {})) f[j].calculated.apply(f[j]);
        }
    }
    if(e.tbody)
    for(j = 0; j < e.tbody.length; j++){
        f = e.tbody;
        for(k = 0; k < f.length; k++){
            //g = f[j];
            if(isFunction(f[j].calculated || {})) f[j].calculated.apply(f[j]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(performance.now() - start);
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names, this code is very hard to read. (I stopped when I tried to find out whether `config[e][f]` is the same as `e.tfoot[j]`.)

Comment: [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/) when it's available

Comment: Your two code examples don't look like they're doing the same thing. Maybe they are, but it's hidden behind the data we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, because of this bit:

> ```
> for(j = 0; j < e.thead.length; j++){
>     f = e.thead;
>     for(k = 0; k < f.length; k++){
>         //g = f[j];
>         if(isFunction(f[j].calculated || {})) f[j].calculated.apply(f[j]);
>     }
> }
> ```

Here you're basically iterating the same thing twice, nested which kills performance. Just omit that one of the loops - you also may notice that you're never using `k` in the loop body.

It should be just

```
if(e.thead) {
    f = e.thead;
    for(k = 0; k < f.length; k++){
        //g = f[j];
        if(isFunction(f[k].calculated || {})) f[k].calculated.apply(f[k]);
    }
}
```

Notice that `f == "thead"` and that `j` is never used in your `forEach` version.

You really should use more descriptive variable names, then things such as this would would be far more obvious. `e` and `f` are not synonymous in the two versions either.

Comment: Yikes, you're right. That'll make a big difference. He could shorten the code a little to by getting rid of `.apply()` and by emulating the `forEach()`.

Comment: @squint: Since I didn't know what exactly `apply` is in his case, I did not dare to touch it. But that statement does look suspicious indeed.

Comment: Yeah, probably a good idea to leave it alone. Most likely a `Function#apply` because of the `isFunction()` call, but who knows. I was so stuck on trying to figure out his variables that I totally missed the redundant looping. Nice one!

Comment: It is indeed `Function#apply`. I just did it to set `this` on the function, but I could have just passed it in as a variable. Just curious -- is that the way to do that?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: You didn't set `this` to the function, but to the `f[k]` object. A simple method call `f[k].calculated()` would have done the same.

Comment: So `f[k].calculated.apply(f[k])` is the same as `f[k].calculated()`?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: Yes, that's what I said.